# Use added class as trigger in jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, if-statement

I'm using [THIS onepage-scroll.js](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) Plugin which gives the active content section a class .active. Now I want to hide an element when on the first section with the class .page1. So I wrote the following code:

```
if ( $('.page1.ops-section').hasClass("active")) {
    $('#navbar').animate({
        opacity: 0.0,
        height: "0px" }, 400
    );
 }
 else {
    $('#navbar').animate({
        opacity: 1,
        height: "60px",
        color: "red"}, 400
    );
 }
```

It checks if the .page1 div has the class .active and if so the #navbar div get's opacity:0. Else it get's opacity: 1. I placed this inside a $(document).ready(function() thing, but this only checks the condition when the page is loaded, I need to add something that does:

```
IF .page1 hasNo .active DO #navbar.animate
and that get's triggered whenever a div get's this .active class
```

Any ideas?

Comment: HTML, can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Can't you just use `afterMove` callback of plugin to check it?

Comment: What do you mean by: `afterMove callback`? How does this work?

It's a bigger site, creating a fiddle to cover the whole problem is a lot of work, if I can't find a quick solution I will create one.

Comment: Oh lord, you are so right Wolff! Everything is way easier to solve using the build-in `afterMove` thing - thanks for the eye opener!